# SoundCloud iOS SDK architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, soundcloud, cpu-architecture

Im working on a music streaming iOS project and want to leverage the SoundCloud SDK.

I followed this guide to the tee:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart

> The five SoundCloud dependencies are:
>
> 1. CocoaSoundCloudAPI
> 2. OAuth2Client
> 3. JSONKit
> 4. OHAttributedLabel
> 5. CocoaSoundCloudUI
>
> All five of these projects are available as submodules that you simply add to your current git repository. According to the guide linked above, you are supposed to be able to add them and move on with your project.  However, their architectures are all different! CocoaSOundCloudAPI, JSONKit, OHAttributedLabel and CocoaSoundCloudUI are all 32bit architecture projects, while OAuth2Client is a 64bit architecture project.

No matter what I build my project as, 32 or 64bit, I get a Mach-O linker error. I've added both 32bit and 64bit as Valid Architectures in my main Xcode Project, but the issue persists.

I have also not been able to find other versions of these submodules. I can't be the only one with this problem, as I have literally followed the guide word by word, yet I can't find any solution anywhere.

Please help me out!

I am using Xcode 6 and building for the iOS8 SDK.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here are screenshots of my architectures and the error...
[image: arhitectures]
[image: erroes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that helped me:

1. Go to the SmartSpeakers target (or whichever is the target for your app)
2. Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags
3. Add `$(inherited)`
4. Build it!

Comment: Holy crap man, it worked!
I gave up on finding a solution to this months ago! You're awesome, how did you figure this out?

Comment: It was a warning that `pod install` kept throwing, so I decided to add it in. Glad it worked for you too! I think all it really does is makes sure that the pods and your own targets get built for the same architectures? Honestly, I have no idea. Linker errors are my least favourite errors.

Answer (score 4):

I HIGHLY suggest using CocoaPods to manage this dependency. I once integrated SoundCloud into a project without using CocoaPods and it was a pain in the rear. Look at this link and do a search for CocoaPods to see how to install it: https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI

Comment: Hey, it didn't work. 

I installed and initiated all the pods, but got the same linker error I was getting earlier.

Answer (score 2):

CocoaPods was the way to go for me.  My Podfile looks like this:

```
pod 'CocoaSoundCloudAPI', '1.0.1'
pod 'CocoaSoundCloudUI', '1.0.5'
pod 'JSONKit', :podspec => 'https://gist.github.com/marcdown/5282955/raw/2a52cfd92f112f2a52669420c82c1bb1efd15d2a/JSONKit.podspec'
```

As of the time of this post, the podspec fetches version 1.6.0.  I experienced problems with some deprecation issues in earlier versions of JSONKit.  If one leaves out the pod for JSONKit, an earlier version that contains these issues is installed by Cocoapods.

I also had to disable ARC for the JSONKit pod in its Build Settings to silence ARC errors:

Pods-JSONKit -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - Objective C

This did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to deploy to a 64-bit device?  Try setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` under Targets -> Your App -> Build Settings -> Architectures.

EDIT: I followed the instructions and created a sample project that builds. I couldn't figure out exactly why you were getting that linker error, but maybe you can compare my project to yours.

http://lieberman.nyc/sample_soundcloud_project_for_relatively_slow_on_stackoverflow.zip

Comment: I'm just trying to get it to work on the simulator for now. 
I've tried simulating several different iPhone generations with the same result.
I tried your suggestion but had no luck.

Comment: @relatively_slow can you post your full compilation log in the original post?  What file is giving you the linker error?

Comment: @relatively_slow I added a sample project that builds following your instructions.  Maybe you can compare my project settings to yours and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @relatively_slow Have you taken a look at my sample project?  Is there anything else you still need help with>

Comment: hey man, I compiled your code, and as is, it works fine. 
However, when you try to actually implement any of the classes in the SDK (I imported SCRequest.h to test a playback), I get the same error. 
Could you do me a favor and try to import SCRequest.h and perform a quick request?

Comment: I'm having this same problem - builds fine if i don't import anything, then it blows up with the same errors once I start importing soundcloud headers. Hope the Soundcloud guys can figure this out! I'm on Xcode 6.1, building for iOS 8.1 and iOS Simulator iPhone 6.